# How do you update an element after adding it to a database using AngularJS http calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, database, http

So currently, I have a method that adds my objects to my database. It works, and is written as such:

```
    var $scope.insertToDB = function(myObj){
        $http.put("my_DB_Link", myObj).then(function(success){
            console.log(success);
        },function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

I figured that updating this object would be fairly easy, but so far, I have been proven wrong. I have used GET to test to assure my data is in there, and so far it is, but with an "_id" tag added onto it. Now, I figured that I could use the same method to update the data:

```
    var $scope.updateObjInDB = function(myObj){
        $http.put("my_DB_Link", myObj).then(function(success){
            console.log(success);
        },function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

But, this always returns a **400 Bad Request** exception. When I replace the "put" with "get" it gets the data without a problem it seems, however, it doesn't seem like you can update the object with the "put" call. Also, "post" throws a **405 Method Not Allow** exception. How do I update my object using a similar method my insertToDB() function?

Comment: Are you trying to update an HTML element?

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at your server API and the methods it supports.

Comment: They are JSON objects