# In AngularJS http requests, what does the error "_id is a reserved field" mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

After further inspection of the issue in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906841/how-do-you-update-an-element-after-adding-it-to-a-database-using-angularjs-http?noredirect=1#comment65173920_38906841), I noticed that I received an **"error":_id is a reserved feild** exception. What exactly does this mean and can you suggest any ways to fix the issue?

Comment: Sounds you're trying to modify a primary key.. what exactly is it that you're doing?

Comment: I just created a JSON object, then added it to the database, which worked. Then I tried to change an arbitrary value in the object (not whatever _id is), and then update the entire object. The error code is 1001, if that helps at all.